# Is it possible to run Craft CMS on Google's Cloud Run?

Tags: deployment

I've been able to get Craft to run on Google App Engine (GAE), but not Cloud Run as of yet.

The error message I'm seeing in the browser is:

`/app/craftcms/storage/runtime isn't writable by PHP. Please fix that.`

I encountered this error when deploying to GAE and the solution was to have the Dockerfile run a shell script that `chmod 755 -R ./storage`. This approach does not work for Cloud Run as I still see the same message in the browser despite running the same script.

I know that Cloud Run is stateless, but we don't need to run admin functions while it's deployed to Cloud Run, so I can't see this being an issue. Has anyone else successfully deployed to Cloud Run?

Comment: Hi @Eric!

May I ask how you managed to run Craft CMS on GCP App Engine Standard?

As far as I understand you only have write access to /tmp on App Engine Standard, so I tried to set the following variable in bootstrap.php:

define('CRAFT_STORAGE_PATH', '/tmp');

But I still get an error on GCP:
mkdir(): Read-only file system in /workspace/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers/BaseFileHelper.php on line 711

Cheers
Michael

Comment: @MichaelHunziker we used Memorystory's Memcached for temporary files, Google Cloud Storage for image transformation variants via the GCS plugin, and disable logging to a file in production (obviously) and route through stdout.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Eric!

Comment: If you don't mind me asking:

So you use Memcached for tmp files, for example the cpresources, right?

How have you been able to "serve" these cpresources? Do you have a special handler defined in your GCP app.yaml for this?

Comment: Never mind...

I just figured out this is the only handler i need:

entrypoint: serve web/index.php

handlers:

  - url: .*
    script: auto

Comment: Sure thing @MichaelHunziker - happy to help

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried Cloud Run but whenever I've had this issue it was due to the folder not having permissions for the user/group that PHP runs as. Typically it's `www-data:www-data`. In other words you might need to use `chown` instead of `chmod`.